# How to update Capybara profile?

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, capybara

I am using code like this to set up Capybara profile:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_focus do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :firefox, profile: profile)
end
```

Later in the setup process, I want to update the profile. For example:

```
  profile["focusmanager.testmode"] = true
```

How to update the profile after it has been set up with `profile["focusmanager.testmode"] = true`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible. The easiest solution is to register 2 drivers with the different settings wanted and then use the correct driver for each test

Comment: because it's set when the browser instance is created/launched and webdriver protocol doesn't provide any methods for updating it (that I've ever noticed anyway)

Comment: I guess it would be possible to do some monkey patching though?

Comment: Not really - you can't monkey patch your way around the feature not being in selenium.  Why can't you just register a new driver?